# How to pass options to CustomType in `collection` field Symfony 2.1?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have `SuperType` Form for Entity `Super`.

In this form I have a `collection` field of `ChildType` Form types for Entity `Child`

**`class SuperType:`**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('childrens', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ChildType(null, array('my_custom_option' => true)),  
}
```

**`class ChildType:`**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if ($options['my_custom_option']) {
        $builder->add('my_custom_field', 'textarea'));
    }
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
  $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      ...
      'my_custom_option' => false
  ));
}
```

How can I change the `my_custom_option` value only for this `SuperType` form?

Of course, what I've tried passing this option via constructor doesn't work.

Comment: Just leave a [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25675#issuecomment-355377999) with the same resolved problem here

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can pass an [array of options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options) to your childType as follows:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('childrens', 'collection', array(
            'entry_type' => new ChildType(),  
            'entry_options'  => array(
                'my_custom_option' => true,
            ),
    // ...

}
```

Comment: Consider updating your answer, as this is deprecated now

Answer (score 13):

In Symfony 3, this is called [entry_options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#entry-options).

```
$builder->add('childrens', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => ChildType::class,
    'entry_options'  => array(
        'my_custom_option'  => true
    ),
));
```