# Passing options to a Symfony form which has entity class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Here is the situation:
I have a parent form which has some fields which are collections.

In need to pass some options to the child form so that it knows if displaying or not a certain field, and if making it required or not.

Here is a snippet:

```
$builder->add('scopesHistory', 'collection',
    array(
        'type' => new ProjectDetailScopeFormType(
             array('required' => false, 'cssClass' => 'hidden')
        ),
        'by_reference' => true, 
        'required'     => true,
        'attr'         => array('class' => ' hidden')
    )
)
```

the child form is the following:

```
class ProjectDetailScopeFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $req = $options['required']; //not working
        $css = $options['cssClass']; //not working

        $builder->add(
            'scope', 
            'text', 
            array(
                'label'      => 'Scope', 
                'required'   => $req,
                'attr'       => array('class' => $css),
                'label_attr' => array('class' => $css)
            )
        ); 
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setRequired(array(
            'required','cssClass'
        ));
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ProjectDetailScope',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ProjectDetailScope';
    }
}
```

it throws the error:

```
The required option "cssClass" is missing.
```

I've also tried to eliminate the part:

```
$resolver->setRequired(array('required', 'cssClass'));
```

but it throws:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cssClass
```

The underlying data structure is of a ProjectDetail entity which has an array collection of ProjectDetailScope entities as children.

Everything is working apart from that "little" detail.

The problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703196/how-to-pass-custom-options-to-a-symfony-form), but there you don't have nested forms. I don't call the create form for the child.

**EDIT:**

The problem seems the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479032/how-to-pass-options-to-customtype-in-collection-field-symfony-2-1) as suggested in one of the comments, but the problem persists. Changing my add as follows:

```
$builder->add('scopesHistory', 'collection', array(
         'type' => new ProjectDetailScopeFormType(), 'options'  => 
              array('required'=>false, 'cssClass'=>'hidden'),
             'by_reference' => true, 'required' => true, 
             'attr'=>array('class'=>' hidden')))
```

as it gave me the error:

```
 The option "cssClass" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "allow_extra_fields", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled", "empty_data", "error_bubbling", "error_mapping", "extra_fields_message", "inherit_data", "intention", "invalid_message", "invalid_message_parameters", "label", "label_attr", "label_format", "mapped", "max_length", "method", "pattern", "post_max_size_message", "property_path", "read_only", "required", "translation_domain", "trim", "validation_groups", "virtual".
```

**EDIT2**

I forgot to declare:

```
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ProjectDetailScope',
        'required'=>true,
        'cssClass'=>''
    ));
```

Now it's solved ;)

Comment: It looks wrong that you're passing those options into the constructor of the child form type. Don't you need an 'options' key somewhere. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#options

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass options to CustomType in \`collection\` field Symfony 2.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479032/how-to-pass-options-to-customtype-in-collection-field-symfony-2-1)

Comment: Thank you Thomas Potaire, it indeed seems the same problem, but the solution does not work for me, see my edited question

Comment: Ok, it works, I forgot the setDefaults(). Thank you!